# How to Remove Mailed-by Header in CakePHP2.2?

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I'd like to know how to remove 'Mailed-by' header in CakePHP2.2.

When I get Email, the name of my server shows like 'via +++.jp'.
I think I should remove or change this information because it'll disclose my host server name.

I found below blog but it didn't work in my version.
http://my-cakephp.blogspot.ie/2010/02/how-to-remove-mailed-by-header-in.html

I'm using 'email configuration file' and I put 'email.php' under 'Config' directory.
Then I add 'additionalParams' => '-f ' into email.php like below.

---

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'no-reply@*****.com',
        'additionalParams' => '-f ',
    );
}
```

---

Does anybody know solution?

Thanks.

Comment: tell us what you have tried or what exactly is not working

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your reply. I've just edited the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Does anybody know solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the CakePHP documentation as your initial source for solutions. I did not take a look at the link you posted but here is what I found:

I took a look at the CakeEmail class and noticed there is a constant called EMAIL_CLIENT being set to ['CakePHP Email'](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-CakeEmail.html#EMAIL_CLIENT)

I then did a search to see where is it being used within the class: [$headers['X-Mailer'] = self::EMAIL_CLIENT;](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-CakeEmail.html#709)

I noticed that the class sets that when ever [the 'X-Mailer' header is not defined](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-CakeEmail.html#708)

That being said, I deduce that if you [set the X-Mailer header in your configuration file](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configurations) you will no longer see 'Mailed by CakePHP Email'.

The API and the Manual are great resources. Good luck!